# Need to show a popup on selecting a layer option in leafletjs

Tags: leaflet

[image]I am trying to show a set of options using the layerGroup functionality to filter out the markers. I need to show a popup when an option is selected from a layer which will prompt the user to enter a number based on which i will be showing the markers. Is this possible as i am new to leafletjs?

In the below sketch, there' s a sample filter at the top right which i intend to show using the layers but the thing is on selecting the 'Location' option i have to show a popup that will prompt the user to enter a location number and on that basis the markers would should be populated.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Not sure exactly what you try to achieve… Any chance you could "sketch" what should happen?